# How to set up a proxy on a Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, proxy

Dear all,
  Is it possible to configure a proxy server for Https web browsing in samsung galaxy tab?
What if I install an ubuntu on it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Ubuntu questions should be asked somewhere else.  Ubuntu has had proxy support for a long time and it is basically independent of the device.

Comment: My main question is about the android 2.2 installed on samsung galaxy tab by default.

Comment: And I only addressed the Ubuntu part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [HTTP Proxy Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/http-proxy-settings/org.credil.proxysettings).

Comment: But does it require a rooted phone?

Comment: I don't believe so.